# JAVA quiz - Same question repeating while answers do cycle correctly

Tags: java

I'm doing a quiz that has a sequence of 3 questions. After choosing the right or wrong answer, it should go to the next question and present the next set of possible answers.

My code does show the answers correctly, but the question repeats itself three times. As another side effect, the set of three quizzes become nine, with the following order: Q1/A1, Q1/A2, Q1/A3, Q2/A1, Q2/A2, Q2/A3, Q3/A1, Q3/A2, Q3/A3.

The desired result is Q1/A1, Q2/A2, Q3/A3.

Here is my code:

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Quiz {

    private static String answer = null;
    private static String answer2 = null;
    private static String answer3 = null;

    static int nQuestions = 0;
    static int nCorrect = 0;

    //Main program, will call the questions to be answered in the quiz and checks if it's correct
    //counting both the number of questions and correct answers.
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String question = "What is the planet with fastest orbit?\n";
        check(question, answer);
        nQuestions = nQuestions+1;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Out of " + nQuestions + " you had "+ nCorrect + " correct answers");

        String question2 = "The sum of 2 + 2.0 is?\n";
        check(question2, answer2);
        nQuestions = nQuestions+1;

        String question3 = "What is the sport the player shoots the ball in a basket\n";
        check(question3, answer3);
        nQuestions = nQuestions+1;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Out of " + nQuestions + " you had "+ nCorrect + " correct answers");
    }


    //The quiz #1
    static String ask(String question) {

        question += "A. Mercury, with a rotation that takes 58d 16h.\n";

        question += "B. Earth, with a rotation that takes 23h 56m.\n";

        question += "C. Mars, with a rotation that takes 24h 36m.\n";

        question += "D. Venus, with a rotation that takes 243d 26m.\n";

        question += "E. Uranus, with a rotation that takes 17h 14m.\n";

        String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);

        answer = answer.toUpperCase();

        while (!answer.equals("A") && !answer.equals("B") && !answer.equals("C") && !answer.equals("D") && !answer.equals("E")) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid answer. Please enter A, B, C, D, or E.");
            answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);
            answer = answer.toUpperCase();

        }

        return answer;  

    }


    //The quiz #2
    static String ask2(String question2) {

        question2 += "A. 4\n";

        question2 += "B. 4.0\n";

        question2 += "C. 3\n";

        question2 += "D. 5\n";

        question2 += "E. -4\n";

        String answer2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question2);

        answer2 = answer2.toUpperCase();

        while (!answer2.equals("A") && !answer2.equals("B") && !answer2.equals("C") && !answer2.equals("D") && !answer2.equals("E")) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid answer. Please enter A, B, C, D, or E.");
            answer2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question2);
            answer2 = answer2.toUpperCase();

        }

        return answer2;

    }


    //The quiz #3
    static String ask3(String question3) {

        question3 += "A. Basketball.\n";

        question3 += "B. Volleyball.\n";

        question3 += "C. Baseball.\n";

        question3 += "D. Football.\n";

        question3 += "E. Tennis\n";

        String answer3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question3);

        answer3 = answer3.toUpperCase();

        while (!answer3.equals("A") && !answer3.equals("B") && !answer3.equals("C") && !answer3.equals("D") && !answer3.equals("E")) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid answer. Please enter A, B, C, D, or E.");
            answer3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question3);
            answer3 = answer3.toUpperCase();

        }

        return answer3;

    }





    //Answer verifier
    static void check(String question,  String correctAnswer) {
        String answer = ask(question);
        String correct = "D";
        if (answer.equals(correct)) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct!");
             nCorrect = nCorrect+1;
            }

        else if (answer.equals("A") || answer.equals("B") || answer.equals("C") || answer.equals("E")) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect! The answer is " + correct);
        }

        //checking Quiz#2
        String answer2 = ask2(question);
        String correct2 = "B";
        if (answer2.equals(correct2)) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct!");
             nCorrect = nCorrect+1;
            }

        else if (answer2.equals("A") || answer2.equals("C") || answer2.equals("D") || answer2.equals("E")) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect! The answer is " + correct2);

        }


        //checking Quiz#3
        String answer3 = ask3(question);
        String correct3 = "A";
        if (answer3.equals(correct3)) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct!");
             nCorrect = nCorrect+1;
            }

        else if (answer3.equals("B") || answer3.equals("C") || answer3.equals("D") || answer3.equals("E")) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect! The answer is " + correct3);

        }       
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner java student and I do realize some sort of unintended loop, but I'm not being able to fix it.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Somewhat of an aside, but I recommend learning about arrays. They solve the problem of having tons of repeated code and typing variables like `thing1`, `thing2`, `thing3`, etc.

Comment: I see `check()` being called three times but I don't see where any of the `ask()` methods are called.  Oversight?

Comment: Addendum: overall your code is good.  Breaking the problem into smaller problems by using methods like this is the right way to go.  However it looks like when you did that you forgot to add the `ask()` methods to the main method.  Easy to do, but go back and read your main method carefully, you haven't got it fixed up right quite yet.

Comment: @markspace - he's calling the `ask` methods in his `check` function

Comment: Welcome. It's good that you included the symptom "As another side effect, the set of three quizzes become nine." and included your code. I'd recommend learning about debuggers (they allow you to step through your code line-by-line and inspect the values of variables. If you used one of these, you'd see that your 'check' method calls ask1, ask2 and ask3 every time - not just for the question string you passed it. I'd suggest simplifying it first (reduce the code you are looking at) and get it working for two questions, before then adding a third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

There are **a lot** of issues with your code, but since you've just started that's understandable.

You should really consider using arrays, and that's why I added one for you so you can get a feel for them.

Your main issue was that you are using the same answer selections for each question 3 times.

The following code should give you what you want:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Quiz {

    private static String answer = null;
    private static String answer2 = null;
    private static String answer3 = null;

    static int nQuestions = 0;
    static int nCorrect = 0;

    //Main program, will call the questions to be answered in the quiz and checks if it's correct
    //counting both the number of questions and correct answers.
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] questions = {"What is the planet with fastest orbit?\n",
                "The sum of 2 + 2.0 is?\n",
                "What is the sport the player shoots the ball in a basket\n"
        };

        nQuestions = questions.length;

        checkQuestions(questions, answer3);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Out of " + nQuestions + " you had "+ nCorrect + " correct answers");
    }


    //The quiz #1
    static String ask(String question) {

        question += "A. Mercury, with a rotation that takes 58d 16h.\n";

        question += "B. Earth, with a rotation that takes 23h 56m.\n";

        question += "C. Mars, with a rotation that takes 24h 36m.\n";

        question += "D. Venus, with a rotation that takes 243d 26m.\n";

        question += "E. Uranus, with a rotation that takes 17h 14m.\n";

        String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);

        answer = answer.toUpperCase();

        while (!answer.equals("A") && !answer.equals("B") && !answer.equals("C") && !answer.equals("D") && !answer.equals("E")) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid answer. Please enter A, B, C, D, or E.");
            answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);
            answer = answer.toUpperCase();

        }

        return answer;

    }


    //The quiz #2
    static String ask2(String question2) {

        question2 += "A. 4\n";

        question2 += "B. 4.0\n";

        question2 += "C. 3\n";

        question2 += "D. 5\n";

        question2 += "E. -4\n";

        String answer2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question2);

        answer2 = answer2.toUpperCase();

        while (!answer2.equals("A") && !answer2.equals("B") && !answer2.equals("C") && !answer2.equals("D") && !answer2.equals("E")) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid answer. Please enter A, B, C, D, or E.");
            answer2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question2);
            answer2 = answer2.toUpperCase();

        }

        return answer2;

    }


    //The quiz #3
    static String ask3(String question3) {

        question3 += "A. Basketball.\n";

        question3 += "B. Volleyball.\n";

        question3 += "C. Baseball.\n";

        question3 += "D. Football.\n";

        question3 += "E. Tennis\n";

        String answer3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question3);

        answer3 = answer3.toUpperCase();

        while (!answer3.equals("A") && !answer3.equals("B") && !answer3.equals("C") && !answer3.equals("D") && !answer3.equals("E")) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid answer. Please enter A, B, C, D, or E.");
            answer3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question3);
            answer3 = answer3.toUpperCase();

        }

        return answer3;

    }


    //Answer verifier
    static void checkQuestions(String[] questions,  String correctAnswer) {
        String answer = ask(questions[0]);
        String correct = "D";
        if (answer.equals(correct)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct!");
            nCorrect = nCorrect+1;
        }

        else if (answer.equals("A") || answer.equals("B") || answer.equals("C") || answer.equals("E")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect! The answer is " + correct);
        }

        //checking Quiz#2
        String answer2 = ask2(questions[1]);
        String correct2 = "B";
        if (answer2.equals(correct2)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct!");
            nCorrect = nCorrect+1;
        }

        else if (answer2.equals("A") || answer2.equals("C") || answer2.equals("D") || answer2.equals("E")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect! The answer is " + correct2);

        }


        //checking Quiz#3
        String answer3 = ask3(questions[2]);
        String correct3 = "A";
        if (answer3.equals(correct3)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct!");
            nCorrect = nCorrect+1;
        }

        else if (answer3.equals("B") || answer3.equals("C") || answer3.equals("D") || answer3.equals("E")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect! The answer is " + correct3);

        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions about what I did.  I tried to keep as much of the code the same while fixing the issue.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. I'm now studying arrays as you and ggorlen have suggested, so I can avoid silly mistakes like the previous one :)